# Something just "tweaked" the quality of my desktop icons in XP

Tags: windows-xp, icons, desktop-icons

Help! I was just now using Tweak UI to change some simple settings, like the mouse wheel, some contents in the start menu, etc. I am not aware of having changed any icon settings/thumbnail quality settings, etc.

And after OK'ing, my desktop icons look like this sorry bunch:

[image]

What to do to revert back to the better quality ones?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe Windows users see what is wrong right away, but even then: could you explain a bit of *what* has changed? (That is also nice for search engines.)

Comment: It seems that my color depth had changed from 32 to 16bits. I don't know how/why it did swictch like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like... you have changed the color depth in all Windows. Just go to Control Panel and in screen properties, advanced tab, change it back to 32bits.(full color, 24bits, however it says it)

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Now I'm very curious what/how/why that was changed. Again, I was using Tweak UI, but consciously made no changes like the one you suggested. hmm...

Comment: Glad it worked :) (it could be you changed some setting to add performance to the system)